# Using typed Set in CoreData NSManaged relationship

Tags: core-data, swift2, xcode7, nsset

When you create a managed object relationship (i.e. one to many), and then you create a NSManagedObject subclass, you would code that relationship like:

```
@NSManaged var dogs: NSSet
```

But I found out that instead you can write:

```
@NSManaged var dogs: Set<Dog>
```

Which in my opinion, it is much more convenient because you have a typed Set and casting in Swift is quite verbose.

**Edited:**
Actually, I have found out that you can use the `insert` and `remove` method of the Set so it's even easier.

I know about Swift automatic [bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html) from some Foundation classes to Swift classes (i.e. `NSArray` to `Array` and `NSSet` to `Set`).

But I haven't found about using Swift typed Sets for implementing Core Data Managed object subclasses in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html) or in any other tutorial and I wonder why.

I'm using Xcode 7.2 and Swift 2 and it works fine in my project. Does it also work for someone else? some Apple doc somewhere? or is it a bad idea for some reason I'm missing?

Comment: It works, and is a great approach.  I've been doing that in several of my projects.

Comment: Thanks @PetahChristian for the confirmation.

Comment: @PetahChristian could you confirm that the `insert` and `remove` methods of the `Set` also work? Because it's working for me and then I find quite stupid the approach of adding the `@NSManaged addX` funcions.

Comment: I have this question to can I change the insert and remove methods to a typed set?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is common practice among many developers as far as I know.

In fact, the generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses are not at all perfect when it comes to the generated types. For examples, primitives still have problems, and `NSNumber` sometimes bridges successfully to `Bool`, sometimes not. Quite often I had to modify the *optional* state as well.

If you leave the preset `NSSet`, you can still cast to `Set<Type>` which is what I did before getting into the habit of changing the generated subclasses' to-many properties to typed sets.

Comment: Actually, I've just found out today in my own and I was wondering if there is some Apple doc somewhere (blog entry or tutorial it's also ok), because I find this quite useful. If you can provide a link that would confirm the statement about common practice and I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: I do not see how a blog entry holds more authority than seasoned StackOverflow members. In fact, many blog entries and tutorials are wrought with errors and omissions. I can confirm that Apple has not addressed this in the official documentation (and there would be good reasons why this is not necessary). I could give more details by way of a technical explanation, or expand on how the `NSSet` convention grew out of the Objective-C legacy, but I do not believe this to be of any productive value.

Comment: Because you stated that it's common practice. I have also reviewed the Apple official docs and WWDC and in the examples they use `NSSet` and I haven't found any StackOverflow questions neither (apart from a couple of them which I answered myself). The question is if this works for someone else (which is already confirmed) and why it's not mentioned somewhere else.